# Connecting to a SQlite database and extracting information dialy

Tags: sqlite

I am here again, now asking for help with something else. Now my problem is that I have connected a SQlite 3 database with ODBC but i do not know how to read and take out information from it.
Looking in youtube tutorials I reached the Management studio for Microsoft SQL Server, but I do not believe this program could help me out.

Comment: You need tutorials on how to use ODBC, not SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to install a SQLite ODBC Driver on your target machine. Then you have to go into your administration tools and add the proper database.

See the link below for a detailed tutorial.

https://faimsproject.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/MobileUser/pages/81595619/How+to+connect+to+an+SQlite3+database+with+Access+as+a+frontend